# Qgis not computing raster stats in layer properties - metadata?

Tags: qgis, metadata, rasterstats

I used to check the sum of all values of a raster (to get some volume information) from the layer properties - Metadata - properties tab, where I had directly the figure I was looking for.

However, since a few weeks, I realised that the layer statistics are not computed any more.

[image: Statistics not computed]

Is there a way to tell Qgis to compute these data?

I have the feeling that this is a bug linked with the 2.18 upgrade, as I realised the misbehaviour a short time after it. Is this general or just happening on my side?

It might also be worth mentioning that I removed a few plug-ins in the upgrade process. I've not seen any plug-in computing these values in the catalogue and would assume it is a core function, but we never know.

Comment: In you can't find that option from QGIS you can create statistics with http://www.gdal.org/gdalinfo.html as `gdalinfo -stats image.tif` I guess that from QGIS you can use Raster-Miscellaneous-Information... and edit the gdalinfo command to include -stats.

Comment: That's the workaround I found while looking around too. Though it does work, it involves writing the info to a shapefile, when all I want is a numeric value for external calculations. (and it's much less straightforward!)

Comment: I do not undestand, what info is written to shapefile? Command probably does write a file named .aux.xml, but once it exists the normal image properties tool of QGIS should find the statistics.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused! You're right, in this case, no info is written, but the sum of all values is not computed, so it's not useful in my particular case!
I was thinking about the zonal statistics plug-in, which uses a polygon to get (among others) the sum of all values in the zone.

Comment: There is a tool in Processing-QGIS-Raster tools-Raster layer statistics which gives the result but it does not seem to be saved anywhere.

Comment: it does look ok, not sure where to find the results dialog though? (I've saved it as html at the moment)

Comment: If I leave output to default [Save to temporary file] the tool opens a new window for the results for me.

Comment: mmm weird, I don't have the window...
The logs says
`Algorithm Raster layer statistics starting...

Converting outputs

Loading resulting layers

Algorithm Raster layer statistics finished

HTML output has been generated by this algorithm.

Open the results dialog to check it.`

But can not find that results dialog.

Comment: @Kantan The results dialog is accessible from the Processing menu: "Results viewer".